# Illustrator: Align bend of shape perfectly to another shape bend

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to have the yellow and red lines 'flowing' exactly alongside the blue line, eliminating the white space between the bends but without distorting them. If I drag the  anchor points, it ruins the bend.

[image]

All 3 of them are shapes which each shape being a 'line' of 2px wide. The width of the shaped line shouldn't change.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an Art Brush for this.

1. Draw three rectangles, and fill each with a colour.
2. Select all, and drag and drop them into the brushes panel
3. When the New Brush dialog appears, choose "Art Brush", click OK
4. Draw a line with curved corners, apply the Art Brush you previously made

Example[image]

Edit: As for making sure the rectangles are 2px high, you can change the units in preferences to pixels. Then draw a rectangle. In the bar along the top you can change the height to 2px.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Interesting approach. How do I make sure the lines are each 2px thick? I'll add that requirement to my question.

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof - I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's close to working. I'm getting a strange first line though, see this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/p9fzSHG.png

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof Looks like the curve is too tight.  Although this solution works, it can't work miracles that go beyond what's physically possible.  You will need to [open up the curve a little](https://imgur.com/Wdu5Yxo). Here I used the corner widget functionality to create the curves - since these can be re-adjusted later at any time.